# Is it possible to use “transmit to” instead of “infect’”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I would like to know whether I could use “transmit to” instead of “infect” in such a sentence:

> Polio does not transmit to animals.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, *transmission of viruses* is correct terminology.

Actually, transmission and infection are two different things. Transmission relates to how a virus could pass from one host to another. Infection refers to the virus gaining a new host, which may not necessarily be directly from another host - for example, you could pick up viral infections from contaminated surfaces.

Answer (score -1):

I think polio can be transmitted to animals (in the sense that they receive it)  but it does not go on to infect them as with human hosts.

Answer (score -1):

**Polio does not transmit to animals* is not an idiomatic English sentence. (I use the convention in linguistics of putting a * before an incorrect sentence.)

[Transmit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transmit) means to carry something to another place. However, it is almost always transitive, e.g. *He transmitted a message to his mother* or *Mosquitos transmit malaria between hosts*.

It's not normal to use it without an object as in **Polio transmits to animals*. According to Merriam-Webster (link as before) it is only used intransitively with radio signals. (*The radio station is transmitting*.)

It would however be OK to use the passive, e.g. *Polio is not transmitted to animals*.

Comment: You won't get a good reputation by dissing other people. Use comments to help improve answers for the good of the site.